# i am getting this error after installation of chaincode network using js?

Tags: javascript, runtime-error, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

Error: chaincode install failed with status: 500 - failed to invoke backing implementation of 'InstallChaincode': chaincode already successfully installed (package ID 'basic_1.0:5e683b01b74f2190bd47dd362292adda50ef65bf565e4cbf8dddbf50b0b19351')

Chaincode installation on peer0.org1 has failed

Deploying chaincode failed

I am getting this error afrer installation of chaincode network using java script

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly shows that the chaincode is already installed, but you are trying to install it one more time.
Try increasing the chaincode version CC_VERSION or restarting the network sample.